# How to make A treeView Table Responsive

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatable, responsive-design, treegrid

Hi below is my tree table structure i would like to make this as reponsive table.i have tree grid with in my table so though datatable responsive is applying responsive is not working expan collapse not working

```html
<table class="tree display responsive no-wrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
    <th>xyz</th>
    <th>zyz</th>
    <th>zyz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
   <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Format your HTML properly with `<tr>...</tr>` around `<th>..</th>` (& end `<th>` properly as shown) & add `<thead>..</thead>` around head & `<tbody>...</tbody>` around body and add code to auto add missing `<td></td>`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add missing <td></td> according to number of columns found in head
    var numTd = $('th').length;
    console.log('Number of columns found in head =: ', numTd);
    $('tbody tr').each(function()
    {
        var i = $(this).find('td').length;
        while(i < numTd)
        {
            $(this).append('<td></td>');
            i++;
        }
    });
    
    $('.tree').DataTable();
} );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<table class="tree display responsive no-wrap">
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>class</th>
    <th>Remark</th>
    <th>xyz</th>
    <th>zyz</th>
    <th>zyz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
   <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please check update - forgot responive lib - now added

Comment: i appreciate your support but sorry to say that its not working DataTable is Applaying but the thing at after 700px Resolution it is not all responsive things being static.

Comment: The (+) in your image shows that responsive is working - but the data not aligning under the headings makes me think there is html formatting that is wrong. Can you provide the code you are using with the xyz 123 data in the image? (Did you Run code snippet of my code and see that the (+) are working?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap for creating responsive table.

**Examlpe:**

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<div class="table-responsive container">
<table class="table table-inverse">
  <tbody>
  <th>name<th>
  <th>class<th>
  <th>Remark<th>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigThing</td>
    <td>somethigvalue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: No way @sachin in this scenarion i have approxmatly  12 tr's it need to get collapse